# Is there an example of a Hausdorff space $X$, where $Y \subset X$, such that $x$ is a limit point of $Y$ but not a sequential limit point of $Y$?

Tags: general-topology

Is there an example of a Hausdorff space $X$, $Y \subset X$, and a point
$x \in X$, such that $x$ is a limit point of $Y$ but not a sequential limit point of $Y$?

I think $0$ will be the limit point of $X$, but not the sequential limit point of $X$. However, I am having a hard time showing that.

Comment: Please don't post images, which cannot be searched.  Instead, take the time to learn *MathJax*.

Comment: done sir. let me know if you have more concerns or questions.

Comment: For "counterexamples in topology" you can see the book by that name.  Or you can use the search features at https://topology.jdabbs.com

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $X=\{0,1\}^\mathbb R$ with the Tychonoff product topology, where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology. Let
$$Y=\{y\in X:y(t)=1\text{ for all but finitely many }t\text{ in }\mathbb R\}$$
and let $x(t)=0$ for all $t$ in $\mathbb R$.

Now $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, and $x$ is a limit point but not a sequential limit point of the subset $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

$\omega_1$ in X = [0,$\omega_1$], Y = [0,$\omega_1$).

Comment: What's $\omega_1$ here? Also, could you please explain and show how you got this?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun It's $Y=\Omega$ and $X=\overline{\Omega}$ in Munkres.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun Or rather (page 66 chapter 1 in 2nd edition) $S_\Omega$ and $\overline{S_\Omega}$. $\Omega$ is then the maximal element of the latter. The treatment in Munkres is very confusing, admittedly. We treated such spaces only after we had a proper course in set theory, instead of a few random remarks about cardinality and well-orderings..

Answer (score 0):

The most standard example is $X=\overline{S_\Omega}$ (notation Munkres' style) which is a well-ordered set such that $X$ is uncountable, and has a maximal element $\Omega$ and such that for all $x \in Y:=S_\Omega = \overline{S_\Omega}\setminus \{\Omega\}$, the "section" $\{y: y < x\}$ is countable and which also has the property that every countable subset $A$ of $Y$ has a supremum in $Y$. See Munkres *Topology* 2nd edition around p. 66/67 in Chapter 1. (edition 1 same pages.)

It follows that by $\Omega$ is a limit point of $Y$, as any basic open neighbourhood in the order topology is of the form $(x, \Omega]$ (as it is the maximal element of $X$) and that set contains (uncountably) many points of $Y$ (as $Y$ is uncountable and there are only countably many points in $Y$ that are $\le x$).

But if $(x_n)$ is any sequence in $Y$, we know $A=\{x_n, n \in \Bbb N\}$ has a supremum $s \in Y$ and then $(s, \Omega]$ is a neighbourhood of $\Omega$ that contains no point of the sequence so $x_n \not\to \Omega$, showing it is not a sequential limit point of $Y$.